# Efficient way to represent numerous object move in Java

Tags: java, performance, set

There are boxes and objects. A object stays in a box. Both box and object have a unique index and each object has a weight.

I need to create a method which obtains numerous orders (> 1 million) in which you can see how much weight should be moved with departure and destination box indices, and then returns moving object set and their destination.

It is very clear and easy to implement without **performance** thought. (Below, the type of box index is Long and object is Integer just for clarification)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Long, Set<Integer>> objectsInBox = new HashMap<>();
    objectsInBox.put(1l, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3)));
    objectsInBox.put(2l, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(4,5,6)));
    // .... a lot of objects
    Map<Integer, Double> weightsOfObject = new HashMap<>();
    weightsOfObject.put(1, 99.9);
    weightsOfObject.put(2, 23.4);
    // ....

    List<Map<Pair<Long, Long>, Double>> moveOrderList = receiveOrderList();
    getFinalDestinationOfMovingObject(moveOrderList);
}

public static Map<Long, Set<Integer>> getFinalDestinationOfMovingObject(
        List<Map<Pair<Long, Long>, Double>> moveOrderList){
    Map<Long, Set<Integer>> finalDestinationOfObjects = new HashMap<>();
    for(Map<Pair<Long, Long>, Double> moveOrder : moveOrderList){
        // Convert moving amount into object move is not trivial, but given somewhere.
        Map<Integer, Pair<Long,Long>> movingObjects = calculateMovingObjectSet(moveOrder);
        for(Map.Entry<Integer, Pair<Long,Long>> movingObject : movingObjects.entrySet()) {
            int movingObjectIndex = movingObject.getKey();
            long departureIndex = movingObject.getValue().getFirst();
            long destinationIndex = movingObject.getValue().getSecond();
            if(!finalDestinationOfObjects.containsKey(destinationIndex)){
                finalDestinationOfObjects.put(departureIndex, new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(movingObjectIndex)));
            }else{
                finalDestinationOfObjects.get(departureIndex).add(movingObjectIndex);
            }
            if(!finalDestinationOfObjects.containsKey(departureIndex)){
                // We need just final destination. Remove past object state.
                finalDestinationOfObjects.get(departureIndex).remove(movingObjectIndex);
            }
        }
    }
    return finalDestinationOfObjects;
}
```

When move order contains numerous elements, it takes a lot of time. I guess it's because insert or remove element from HasSet is not efficient. What is more efficient way?

Comment: Your last `if` is surely wrong (NPE) and the previous one most probably too. How do you know that most of the time is not spent in `calculateMovingObjectSet`? Assuming the maps is really the culprit, you might be able to use a different representation and save yourself moving things between maps.

Comment: @maaartinus Thank, you. I updated my `if` condition. I profiled CPU time with JVM monitor tool in eclipse. I'm sure that `calculateMovingObjectSet` takes about 50% process time.

Comment: It is not possible to give you the most efficient implementation because it is difficult to reverse engineer the exact requirements just by looking at your posted code. If we have the requirements then we can proceed forward to that goal. It is clear from your code though that you maybe doing some unnecessarily heavy processing.

Comment: I'm still thinking, your last condition is wrong. If there's no key `departureIndex`, then your  `get(departureIndex)` must return `null`. Anyway, a more efficient way would be `Set<Integer> tmp = finalDestinationOfObjects.get(departureIndex); if (tmp!=null) ....` avoiding the double lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you simply record the final destination based on the object, i.e.,

```
finalDestination.put(movingObjectIndex, destinationIndex);
```

instead of all the complicated logic? This handles the case of previous destination existing as well as non-existing.

If you really need `finalDestinationOfObjects`, you can create it at the end by something like

```
Multimap<Long, Integer> finalDestinationOfObjects = HashMultimap.create();
for (val e : finalDestination.entrySet()) {
    finalDestinationOfObjects.put(e.getValue(), e.getKey());
}
```

where `Multimap` comes from [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) (you don't need it, but - unlike your nested `Map` - it's the right thing).

This will be more efficient in case your objects moves between the boxes a lot and possibly less efficient in case they usually get moved just once.

I'd suggest to give it a try and post the code together with `calculateMovingObjectSet` on [CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java), which is better suited for such questions.